# Obtener un json desde php para usarlo en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Por ejemplo:

```
   ..datos: 
[
     {a:56, b:"nombre1"},
     {a:26, b:"nombre2"},
     {a:16, b:"nombre3"}
]
```

Dentro de datos: [ .... ] quiero agregar los objetos.

En el php que utilizo tengo :

```
echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Hola Benjamin, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Con respecto a la pregunta, debes mostrar tu código y ser específico al decirnos **que has intentado** y en **donde estás fallando**. Para mas información puedes leer **[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso no te conviene usar `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, ya que si se trata de un array asociativo, te creará un json con índices numéricos cuya lectura será posiblemente más complicada.

Si usas únicamente `echo json_encode($array);` vas a obtener un JSON Array parecido a este:

```
[{
    "a": 56,
    "b": "nombre1"
}, {
    "a": 26,
    "b": "nombre2"
}, {
    "a": 16,
    "b": "nombre3"
}]
```

El cual podrás leer con suma facilidad luego de haberlo parseado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var arrJson=
'[{"a":56, "b":"nombre1"},{"a":26, "b":"nombre2"},{"a":16, "b":"nombre3"}]';
var myJson = JSON.parse(arrJson);

myJson.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('A: ' + item.a);
  console.log('B: ' + item.b);
});
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Comment: @Benjamin Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hola benjamin mira si tienes un array de datos en php solo con codificarlo lo podras usar por ejemplo

```
echo json_encode($array); y listo,
```

para usarlo en js tienes q pasarlo a objeto y le haces un parse asi mira

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

y Listo con eso podras usarlo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Christopher Flores.